# Stored Procedures Why Interpretted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this bothering me for quite a long time.
Is SQL interpreted? If YES, then what about stored procedures? Why does one have to interpret them all the time? This would be very very inefficient...Should they not be compiled and stored for future use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link  : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/soliddb/v6r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.sql.doc/doc/sql.html

3rd bulletpoint:

> SQL is generally an "interpreted" language rather than a "compiled"
>   language. To execute one or more SQL statements, you typically execute
>   a separate program that reads your script and then executes it. No
>   "compiled program" or "executable" is generated and stored for later
>   use. Each time you run the program, it is interpreted again. (Stored
>   Procedures can be re-used without necessarily re-interpreting them.
>   Stored Procedures are discussed briefly in solidDB SQL syntax and
>   extensively in Stored procedures, events, triggers, and sequences.